# Ajax response not fetching all result

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, response

I am trying to fetch some results from database and display them to a table. I am getting the full response which is as below,

Response payload

```
{"groupname":
 [
  {
   "id":12,"group_name":"sd"
  },
  {
   "id":11,"group_name":"ghf"
  },
  {
   "id":10,"group_name":"sdf"
  },
  {
   "id":9,"group_name":"dsf"
  },
  {
   "id":5,"group_name":"g"
  },
  {
   "id":4,"group_name":"too"
  },
  {
   "id":3,"group_name":"lol"
  },
  {
   "id":2,"group_name":"hh"
  },
  {
   "id":1,"group_name":"TestGroup"}

 ],
"question_count":
 [
  {
   "count":1
  },
  {
   "count":3
  },
  {
   "count":1
  },
  {
   "count":6
  },
  {
   "count":1
  },
 {
  "count":5
 }
],
"img_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/O2X\/Trunk\/Web\/public\/admin\/images\/icn_close.png",
"drag_img_url":"http:\/\/localhost\/O2X\/Trunk\/Web\/public\/admin\/images\/drag-handle.png"
}
```

I displayed them into a table by the below code

```
for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
  if (data.groupname[i].group_name) {
              txt = '<tr class="row1" data-id="' + data.groupname[i].id + '"><td>' + data.groupname[i].group_name + '</td>';
                        }
           $("#table").append(txt);
                   }
```

But I am getting only limited groupnames, but there are total 9 group names in the result. When I alert Object.keys(data).length it gives me only 4. So I need to loop through the whole groupnames. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a valid object structure for your input, in Javascript syntax.

Comment: If `groupname` is an array in for loop use `groupname.length` instead of `Object.keys(data)`. If `groupname` is object/dict then do `for (key in Object.keys(data))` and access it as `data[key]["group_name"]`. If you post your JSON structure appropriately it will be lost easier to understand and figure out the issue.

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: @Oops Please see the answer. if you want to iterate over groups, you should do `Object.keys(data.groupname).length`. Also, make it `<` instead of '<=` since you are using `length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting length `4` from the below code as you have 4 objects inside `data` and these are `groupname`, `question_count`, `img_url` and `drag_img_url`.

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

If you want to iterate over groups, you should do:

```
Object.keys(data.groupname).length
```

Secondly, you have used `<=` instead  do `<` since you are using `length`.

As I mentioned as a comment to the original post, since `groupname` is an array you can use `length` of it and iterate.

```js
var data = {
    "groupname": [{ "id": 12, "group_name": "sd" }, { "id": 11, "group_name": "ghf" }, { "id": 10, "group_name": "sdf" }, { "id": 9, "group_name": "dsf" }, { "id": 5, "group_name": "g" }, { "id": 4, "group_name": "too" }, { "id": 3, "group_name": "lol" }, { "id": 2, "group_name": "hh" }, { "id": 1, "group_name": "TestGroup" }],
    "question_count": [{ "count": 1 }, { "count": 3 }, { "count": 1 }, { "count": 6 }, { "count": 1 }, { "count": 5 }], "img_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/O2X\/Trunk\/Web\/public\/admin\/images\/icn_close.png", "drag_img_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/O2X\/Trunk\/Web\/public\/admin\/images\/drag-handle.png"
};
for (var i = 0; i < data.groupname.length; i++) {
    if (data.groupname[i].group_name) {
        txt = '<tr class="row1" data-id="' + data.groupname[i].id + '"><td>' + data.groupname[i].group_name + '</td>';
    }
    console.log(txt);
}
```

Much shorter syntax:

```js
var data = {
    "groupname": [{ "id": 12, "group_name": "sd" }, { "id": 11, "group_name": "ghf" }, { "id": 10, "group_name": "sdf" }, { "id": 9, "group_name": "dsf" }, { "id": 5, "group_name": "g" }, { "id": 4, "group_name": "too" }, { "id": 3, "group_name": "lol" }, { "id": 2, "group_name": "hh" }, { "id": 1, "group_name": "TestGroup" }],
    "question_count": [{ "count": 1 }, { "count": 3 }, { "count": 1 }, { "count": 6 }, { "count": 1 }, { "count": 5 }], "img_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/O2X\/Trunk\/Web\/public\/admin\/images\/icn_close.png", "drag_img_url": "http:\/\/localhost\/O2X\/Trunk\/Web\/public\/admin\/images\/drag-handle.png"
};
data.groupname.forEach(token => {
    txt = '<tr class="row1" data-id="' + token.id + '"><td>' + token.group_name + '</td>';
    console.log(txt);
});
```

**Note:** I have printed `txt` on console instead of appending to a table for demonstration.